# Neural Network loss is significantly changing for same set of weights - Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

```
model = keras.Sequential([
layers.Dense(10, activation = 'relu', weights=[zero_weights, zero_bias]),  
layers.Dense(24, activation = 'relu', weights=[one_weights, one_bias]),
layers.Dense(12, activation = 'relu', weights=[two_weights, two_bias]),
layers.Dense(1, weights=[three_weights, three_bias])])
# Compile Model
model.compile(loss='mse',
            optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1),
            metrics=['mse'])
model.fit(inputs, targets,
          batch_size=5,
          epochs=100)
prediction_test = model.predict(X_test)
mse=mean_squared_error(prediction_test,y_test)
print(mse)
```

I use pre-initialized weights as initial weights of the neural network, but the loss value keeps changing every time I train the model. If the initial weights are the same, then the model should predict exactly the same value every time I train it. But the mse keeps changing. Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the layers initialised to some weights(probably the weights you obtained from the previous training session), but the data you passed it for training will get shuffled differently every time you start the training process since model.fit() api has shuffle param set to True by default. If you set it to False you will not see model weights getting updated during subsequent runs if the training data is the same.

```
model.fit(inputs, targets,
          batch_size=5,
          epochs=100, shuffle=False)
```

Comment: I added the shuffle function, but the code was not still working. The mistake that I did was that the shape of the array I am passing as the weight to one of the layers was not the shape that should be used. Changed the shape from (12, 1) to (12, ). Now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Setting preinitialized values doesn't prevent from training.

Set layer `.trainable` property to False:

```
model.layers[0].trainable = False
```

Comment: But I want the weights to be changed while training. I am only initializing the weights with the weights that I have. If the initial weights are the same, then the loss function should be same every time I train the model.